# Why can't I see the curve when i run ma code in Browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'n a beginner in JavaScrip and Three.js , and Computer Graphics as well. My task today ist to draw the Bezier Curve with de-Casteljau Algorithm. Here is my code but it doesn't work in browser (in general). Can somebody please help me to find the error. Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Aufgabe 1 - Computergrafik</title>
        <style>
            body {margin: 0;}
            canvas {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.x = 0;
            camera.position.y = 0;
            camera.position.z = 20;
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee);

            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var objetos = [], plane;
            var puntos = new Array();
            puntos.push(new THREE.Vector3(1, 4, 0));
            puntos.push(new THREE.Vector3(2, 1, 0));
            puntos.push(new THREE.Vector3(5, 2, 0));
            puntos.push(new THREE.Vector3(6, 6, 0));

            for(var i=0; i < puntos.length; i++){
                var puntoscurvaGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);
                var puntosMesh = new THREE.Mesh(puntoscurvaGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000}));
                puntosMesh.position.x = puntos[i].x;
                puntosMesh.position.y = puntos[i].y;
                puntosMesh.position.z = puntos[i].z; 
                scene.add(puntosMesh);
                objetos.push(puntosMesh);
            }

            var linea;
            var tempPuntos;
            var temp;

            animate();

            function animate(){
                casteljau();
                render();
            }

            function casteljau(){
                var curvaPuntos = new THREE.Geometry();
                for(var i= 0.0; i<=1.0; i+=0.02){
                    temp = getCasteljauPoint(i);
                    curvaPuntos.vertices.push(temp);
                }
                linea = new THREE.Line(curvaPuntos, new THREE.LineBasicMateria({color: 0xff0000}));
                scene.add(linea);
            }

            function getCasteljauPoint(t){
                tempPuntos = [];
                var n = objetos.length-1;
                for(var i=0; i<=n; i++){
                    var p = new THREE.Vector2(objetos[i].position.x, objetos[i].position.y);
                    tempPuntos.push(p);
                }
                for(var j = 1; j<=n; j++){
                    for(var k = 0; m <= (n-j); k++){
                        tempPuntos[k].x = t*tempPuntos[k].x + (1-t)*tempPuntos[(k+1)].x;
                        tempPuntos[k].y = t*tempPuntos[k].y + (1-t)*tempPuntos[(k+1)].y;
                    }
                }
                return new THREE.Vector3(tempPuntos[0].x, tempPuntos[0].y, 0);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors:

Near the bottom, you have

```
for(var k = 0; m <= (n-j); k++){
```

Replace `m` with `k`

```
THREE.LineBasicMateria
```

is missing the `l`

You also have no render function:

```
function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Always check the browser console for errors.

Btw, to get rid of the scrollbars, add `display: block;` to your `canvas` style.

Comment: or, as an option against the scrollbars, `body { overflow: hidden; }`